# Integrating Client-Side Code with Next.js Server Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to implement error handling within a Next.js server component, and I want to display error messages using client-side code, specifically a `<Toast>` component. However, the `"use Client"` function that the `<Toast>` component requires is not accessible within the server component. How can I make this work?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import { getContact, getAddressesByContactId, getUsersByContactId } from 'fetch-data-from-api';

export default async function Page() {
    try {
        const contact = await getContact(id);
        const addresses = await getAddressesByContactId(id);
        const users = await getUsersByContactId(id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("something went wrong") <-- Handling errors with Toast messages
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the full code